# Icon with text inside - how to define in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a `TextView` (to show a count) hovering over an icon in the ActionBar. What I did was have a `RelativeLayout`, set a background to it, then put that `TextView` in that layout and screw with the margin until it fits, but that is broken as soon as the text length varies. 
Setting a background on the `TextView` isn't great either because I can't position the text in relation to the icon.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cart" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"      android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is a screenshot to show you what I mean:

[image]

Is there a stress-free way, a library perhaps, that lets me set a `TextView` over a `Drawable` so that the TextView is always centered/ positioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Setting a background on the TextView isn't great either because I can't position the text in relation to the icon.

Actually you can position your text relative to your icon. You need to separate the cart icon and the number badge icon as separate images, and lay them out individually. I had to do this myself not too long ago, and I did it with a `RelativeLayout`, with an `ImageView` of the cart icon and a `TextView` for the numbers with a 9-patch "badge" as the background.

The trick is to align your number `TextView` to the **left** and **bottom** of your cart icon `ImageView`, and then use the **left** and **bottom** margins to push your number badge to the **top** and **right** of your cart icon. This way, the number badge is always anchored based on your cart icon.

Also, set the `gravity` of your `TextView` to `center`, so as the numbers grow wider, the relative position of the text is about the same. Lastly, use `padding` on your `TextView` to control how much gap there is between the edge of the number and the edge of your "badge" 9-patch.

Here's a snippet of my implementation (I've redacted some of this):

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cartButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cartIconImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_cart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartBadge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cartIconImageView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cartIconImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/state_list_cart_badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="7" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Steven Byle, can you provide the drawable files if you can ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout. It's always called useless but if you ask me it's perfect to lay out one View on top of another.

[Quote](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). Views that are GONE are used for sizing only if setConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring() is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a TextView, and set a 9 patch as the background:

[image: 9 patch file]

You might have to play around with it (I just whipped this up in a minute or two), but something like the very bottom right in the image is what you want. It will be a lot more consistent than dealing with two views.