# ActionBarSherlock Custom ActionBar Layout - home icon is gone

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using a custom layout on my ABS `ActionBar`, like

```
    View abview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custombar, null);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(abview);
```

Now there's no home/ up button, I already tried:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

When using a custom view on my `ActionBar`, do I have to take care of the up button all myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom action view in your action bar, like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");
    }
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_generic, menu);

    // Progress
    final MenuItem progress = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_progress);
    progress.setActionView(R.layout.action_view_progress);

    mProgressText = (TextView) progress.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.total_achievement_text);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

menu_genric.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_progress"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

After, you can increase your number with reference of mProgressText

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and it appears to be dependent on what order you specify things. Here is how I get my custom view to show up, while still preserving the home/back action (this code is in `onCreateOptionsMenu`):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
// 1) Inflate your menu, if you have also need actions
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.normal_action_menu, menu);
// 2) Set your display to custom next
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
// 3) Do any other config to the action bar
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
// 4) Now set your custom view
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
```

Comment: unbelievable but works, I put actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view); on end and solved disappearing of home button

Answer (score 2):

If you use a custom View in ActionBar (ActionBarsherlock) you must manage itself all actionBar. So It's better to keep ActionBar and set xml to background and/or set customview in  specific element.
What do you want to do in your custom actionbar ?

Comment: What I want to do is this: the cart icon with a updatable TextView in it, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227379/icon-with-text-inside-how-to-define-in-layout. You mean I could set a custom view only on that specific icon?